# R can't find function even though I installed its package. .nlmP (from geoR)

Tags: r, package, geor

I write

```
install.packages("geoR")
library(geoR)
.nlmP(f,parameters)
```

and it returns

```
Error: could not find function ".nlmP"
```

What to do?

I  did what the first answer suggest, then it said

```
Error in get(".ind.prof.phi", pos = 1) : object '.ind.prof.phi' not found
```

Comment: Why do you want to use this function in the first place? If it's not exported then the author doesn't intend for it to be used by the end user.

Comment: What other package is available for constrained, non-linear optimization in R?

Comment: Why are you calling this particular hidden function in the first place? Are you following a guide or something. What exactly is the desired output. This function is a private function not meant to be called directly.

Comment: I use "nlm" usually, and so I googled "nlm constraints". It showed up.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think we're quick to judge here.

https://github.com/cran/geoR/blob/a516861572ad6be3c2452a7b187af946130cf439/inst/CHANGES

The CHANGES file specifies that .nlmP was supposed to be exported in 1.7-2 and looking through the history it was.  It wasn't until 1.7-4 or 1.7-5 that it got commented out in the NAMESPACE file. There is a note  "changes to fix issues on CRAN reported errors/warnings regarding namespaces and foreign calls" so it might have been a namespace issue but it does seem the author intended for the function to be exported.

It might make sense to contact the maintainer about this.

If you absolutely need this function you could install the latest version that had it exported.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("cran/geoR", ref = "74feb80")
```

Note that you won't have any of the changes made to the package after that commit.

With that said I'm fairly sure there are better packages for contstrained non-linear optimization so hopefully somebody comes along with a better answer to get at the actual root of your problem.

Comment: This is very informative and helpful. I think it should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `geoR:::.nlmP()`, because `nlmP` is not in the exported NAMESPACE for `geoR`.

Comment: This did not work. It produces Error in get(".ind.prof.phi", pos = 1) : object '.ind.prof.phi' not found

Comment: I don't know the specifics of this package and funciton, but it looks as though it's using some other elements that are *not exported* from the package. Sometimes this is easy to fix, and other times it would be easier simply to download the package source, add the desired function to the NAMESPACE, and rebuild. But it's worth noting that most package authors have thought carefully about which functions to export. Possibly you can get what you want using exported functions.